# Morse Code Converter Code returns invalid output

Tags: java, arrays

I am suppose to do a Morse Code Converter and I have tried everything to try and get it to work but it's just not doing it

It keeps giving me

`r
. ___ ___ ___ ___`

regardless of what I put in. This is my whole code. I understand I can do it by switch or by main but my teacher wont allow it. And the reason I have `intArray = [100]` because it keeps giving me the out of bound error.

```
public class MorseCodeConverter
{       
    public final int NUM_CHARS = 40;
    private String original;
    private String mcode;
    int[] intArray = new int[100];

    char[] character = { ' ', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0' };
    String[] code = { "    ", ". ___", "___ . . .", "___ . ___ .", "___ . .", ".", ". . ___ .", "___ ___ .", ". . . .", ". .", ". ___ ___ ___", "___ . ___", ". ___ . .",  "___ ___", "___ .", "___ ___ ___", ". ___ ___ .", "___ ___ . ___", ". ___ .", ". . .", "_", ". . ___", ". . . ___", ". ___ ___", "___ . . ___", "___ . ___ ___", "___ ___ . .", ". ___ ___ ___ ___", ". . ___ ___ ___", ". . . ___ ___", ". . . . ___", ". . . . .", "___ . . . .", "___ ___ . . .", "___ ___ ___ . .", "___ ___ ___ ___ .", "___ ___ ___ ___ ___"};

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class MorseCodeConverter
     */
    public MorseCodeConverter() { }

    public MorseCodeConverter(String input)
    {
        this.original=input;
    }

    public String toMorse(char ch)
    {  
        String char1 = ("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W XY Z");
        for (int index = 0; index <char1.length(); index++){ 
            for ( int i = 0; i < character.length; i ++) {
                if (char1.charAt(index) == character[i]) {
                    intArray[index] = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return " ";
    }

    public String getMorseCode() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i <intArray.length; i++) {
            int x = intArray[i];
            stringBuilder.append(code[x]);
            break;
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    } 
}

public class MorseCodeConverterDemo
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        //Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        //char userInput=keyboard.;

        MorseCodeConverter mcc = new MorseCodeConverter();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

        // Character input 
        char c = sc.next().charAt(0); 
        mcc.toMorse(c);
        mcc.getMorseCode();
        System.out.println(mcc.getMorseCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not using the ch parameter of `toMorse` anywhere, look into that for a start.

Comment: Why do you have `char1` and why do you have a `break` after `stringBuilder.append`?

Comment: The problem you sated doesn't add up to the code you have posted. The `MorseCodeConverter` class is design for converting a static string which is  `char1` but in your `MorseCodeConverterDemo` class you are taking user input! Try understand your own code and relate it to your problem!

Comment: @Chioma did you checked this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/morse-code-implementation/

Answer (score 0):

There are too many unnecessary lines of code! Let's walk through step by step.
You *do **NOT*** need these class variables -

```
public final int NUM_CHARS = 40;
private String original;
private String mcode;
int[] intArray = new int[100];
```

Constructors are **NOT** necessary as well -

```
public MorseCodeConverter(){
}

public MorseCodeConverter(String input){
    this.original=input;
}
```

Refactor your `toMorse(char c)` method like this -

```
public String toMorse(char c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < character.length; i++) {

        if (c == character[i]) {
            return code[i];
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

Refactor your `getMorseCode()` method like this -

```
public String getMorseCode(String input) {
    StringBuilder morseCodeBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        morseCodeBuilder.append(toMorse(input.charAt(i)));
    }

    return morseCodeBuilder.toString();
}
```

Now, as of your `main()` method, you can use the `MorseCodeConvert` class like this -

```
MorseCodeConverter mcc = new MorseCodeConverter();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

// Character input 
String c = sc.next();

System.out.println(mcc.getMorseCode(c));
```

#### Improvement Suggestion

Instead of defining two `array`s, you can define a `Map`. This will eliminate one extra loop.
first, define the `map`

```
private static final Map<Character, String> CHAR_TO_MORSE_CODE_MAP = new HashMap<>();

static {
    CHAR_TO_MORSE_CODE_MAP.put(' ', "    ");
    CHAR_TO_MORSE_CODE_MAP.put('A', ". ___");
    CHAR_TO_MORSE_CODE_MAP.put('B', "___ . . .");
    CHAR_TO_MORSE_CODE_MAP.put('C', "___ . ___ .");
    //so on...
}
```

Change this line of `getMorseCode(String input)` method

```
morseCodeBuilder.append(toMorse(input.charAt(i)));
```

to this-

```
morseCodeBuilder.append(CHAR_TO_MORSE_CODE_MAP.get(input.charAt(i)));
```

Now, you don't need the `toMorse(char c)` method. That's it!